# How Greasemonkey for IE runs a user java script?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, greasemonkey

Can anybody explain me, **How greasemonkey runs a user script?**
I am looking forward to know the technical details i.e, How and where the script is read and run, at gresemonkey or on the browser?**How the interaction between greasemonkey and browser takes place?**

I know how to install the scripts.
Basically I am using **Greasemonkey for IE** and **IE8**.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The [source code](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/tree) is available on github and Mozilla have extensive [documentation on writing add-ons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/addons).</strike>

… ah, you're talking about "Greasemonkey for IE" and not "Greasemonkey". The source code <strike>is still available, just in a [different place](http://www.gm4ie.com/download.html)</strike>, was still available when this question was asked but it looks like the project has since died. I bet [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) will have equivalent docs somewhere.

Comment: @Brock – yes, I noticed that, I was editing the answer while you commented. I was tricked by the "for IE" not being mentioned until the very end of the question :) (which I've now edited)

Comment: The link for greasemonkey for ie is no longer valid.